# Variable scope for PHP callback functions

Tags: php, oop, callback, scope

In response to another question I asked about regular expressions, I was told to use the `preg_replace_callback` function ([PHP regex templating - find all occurrences of {{var}}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959017/)) as a solution to my problem.  This works great, but now I have a question relating to variable scope in callback functions.

The function that parses the text is part of a class, but the data that I want to use is stored locally in the function.  However, I have found that I cannot access this data from inside my callback function.  Here are the ways that I have tried so far:

- Implement the callback as a private class function, passing `'$this->callback_function'` as the callback parameter (doesn't work, php has a fatal error)
- Implement the callback inside the function that uses it (see example below) but this didn't work either because `$newData` is not in scope inside `callback_function`

Any ideas as to how I can access `$newData` inside my callback function, preferably without using globals?
Many thanks.

Example below for the second attempt (doesn't format properly when I put it after the bullet point)

```
public function parseText( $newData ) {
  ...
  function callback_function( $matches ) {
    ...  //something that uses $newData here
  }
  ...
  preg_replace_callback( '...', 'callback_function', $textToReplace );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Implement the callback as a private class function, passing *'$this->callback_function'* as the callback parameter (doesn't work, php has a fatal error)
>
> preg_replace_callback( '...', 'callback_function', $textToReplace );

Change your call to be `preg_replace_callback ('...', array($this, 'callback_function'), $textToReplace);` while `callback_function` is a private method in your class.

```
<?php

class PregMatchTest
{
    
    private callback_function ($matches)
    {
        // ......
    }

    public function parseText ($newData)
    {
        // ....
        
        preg_replace_callback( '...', array($this, 'callback_function'), $textToReplace );
    }
    
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible without using globals, maybe just set it on the *$_GLOBALS* array and **then unset it** if you wish.